# retrieve the value of input datepicker with a simple function change

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Start with apologizing for my English :-)

I'm using an excellent JQuery plugin "[jQuery Date Range Picker](http://jszen.com/jquery-date-range-picker-plugin.4.html)": http://jszen.com/jquery-date-range-picker-plugin.4.html

In the link provided you can also see examples in detail I am using the example with two inputs (getValue: function () ... setValue: function (s, s1, s2) ...), but I have a big problem: I can not retrieve the value of input1 and input2 with a simple function "change"!

For example if I try to retrieve the values of online example I can Use the following code inserted in the html page:

```
$('#date-range200').on("change", function() {
    var StrDataDa = $(this).val();
    if( StrDataDa == "" ) {
        $("#mySpan").html("0");
    }
    else {
        $('#mySpan').html(StrDataDa);
    }
});
```

When I select the date and close the calendar is not reported in the span that I have called "MySpan" the selected date.

If you change the date manually within "date-range200" all naturally works well ... basically is not recognized the "change" if the input is populated with the plugin.

Please could you help me find a solution? :-)

Thanks

Comment: See the section on **Events** in the documentation: https://rawgit.com/longbill/jquery-date-range-picker/master/index.html. You probably want `datepicker-change`, `datepicker-apply`, or `datepicker-closed`.

Comment: Hi @Barmar , unfortunately I am not very jquery expert, how should I fix the code I mentioned earlier? I tried to replace "$('#date-range200').on("change", function() {" with the specified code "$('#dom-id').dateRangePicker().bind('datepicker-closed',function()" but does not work. Can you help me please? Thanks

Comment: It should be `#date-range200`, not `#dom-id`. That's just a placeholder for the example. And you should use `.on()`, not `.bind()`.

Comment: If you can't extrapolate from examples to your specific situation, you're going to have a really hard time as a programmer. You can't expect everyone to spoon-feed you the exact syntax for your situation, you have to understand what you're doing.

Comment: thanks @Barmar, I try to study better all the suggestions that you have given me. Unfortunately many years that I do not put hand to a jQuery code :-( Later see if I can put online the script for testing. Thanks again for the kindness and helpfulness